# Why is text in ggplot2 geom_text anchoring at center

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I am attempting to create a `ggplot` of some tabular data.  However, no matter what value of `hjust`  I provide in the aesthetic for `geom_text`, the text aligns relative to the center of the field, rather than relative to the left or right margin.

Here is the code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = letters[1:9], b = c('0.0 (-3.1, 3.0)','5.2 (1.6, 8.9)','2.5 (0.9, 4.1)','19.9 (14.7, 25.1)','7.0 (3.7, 10.4)','3.8 (1.3, 6.3)','1.2 (-0.1, 2.5)','0.0 (-0.2, 0.2)','21.4 (16.4, 26.4)'))

t_af <- ggplot(data=df1) +
  geom_text(aes(y=a, x=1, label=b, vjust=0, hjust = 0)) +
  ggtitle("aAF, % (95% CI)") +
  xlab("  ") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 10) +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks  = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="white"),
    plot.title = element_text(size=12, hjust = .5)
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(df1$a))

t_af
```

This results in:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6ShD.png)

If I change the hjust parameter to hjust = 1, I get this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vozIc.png)

Setting `hjust = 0.5`, gives the expected results:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/No9jY.png)

Any help figuring this peculiar behavior out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you take `hjust` and `vjust` our of the `aes()`?

Comment: If you remove the theming you'll see that ggplot adds padding of of 0.05 to either side of your values, which is why they're always near the center. You could add `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,2)) +` so the scale is not centered on 1. The `expand` parameter of that can be adjusted if you want zero padding.

Comment: Like Jon says, the behavior of `hjust` is to align around the `x` value, which is 1 in your case and by default 1 will be in the center of the plot.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Given the suggestions of @JonSpring and @Axeman I was able to solve by adding `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1)` and changing `hjust = 1` in the `aes()`.